# Fixed div inside relative parent is not working as expected in Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-position

I have a fixed div inside of a relative positioned div. I want the div to be fixed to the top of the page and contained within my relative positioned parent.

A common example of this use case is a sticky website sidebar in a two column layout.

As I understand. Setting the `top: 0` on my fixed div will fix it to the top. Setting `margin-left: 0` on my fixed div will align it with its relatively positioned parent.

This works fine on all browsers except Safari (version < 10). Is there any way to fix this issue that doesn't involve user agent sniffing.

Here is a bare-minimum fiddle illustrating isolating issue below:
http://jsfiddle.net/vgc1ekbg/4/

Here's another fiddle illustrating the issue in the context of a two-column website layout: http://jsfiddle.net/dpmj3y0n/1/

Comment: No.... *fixed* positioned elements are always positioned in relation to the **viewport**. Not their parent elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited based on last fiddle shared in comments.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  /* line-height: 580px; */
}
.layout {
  height: 2000px;
  /*padding-left: 20px;*/
  /* padding-right: 350px; */
  /*margin-right: 192px;*/
}
.layout:before, .layout:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.layout:after {
  clear: both;
}
.col-main {
  width: calc(100% - 184px);
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  height: 580px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: #f16529;
  line-height: 580px;
}
.col-sub {
  /* margin-right: -100%; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  line-height: 580px;
  /* height: 580px; */
  background-color: #f0dddd;
  float: left;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: gray;
  color: red;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="col-main">Main Content</div>
    <div class="col-sub">Sidebar Content
      <div class="sticky">
          Sticky Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. However in this case .sticky is no longer stuck to the top of the viewport.

Comment: I edited it preserving your fixed position, if you want it touching the viewport you can change top to 0 but it won't be aligned with the right div.

Comment: Left the example with top: 0; since it was your original value, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Syden. I've updated the question to be more clear and I've added another fiddle. I need my .sticky div to be contained within my sidebar. An example of this is a website with a sticky sidebar widget that follows you down the page. I can get this to work on most browsers but my challenge is it doesn't work on Safari (version < 10). I suspect it has something to do with the way Safari handles margins on fixed elements. Here's an example of my issue in the context of a two column layout: http://jsfiddle.net/dpmj3y0n/1/

Comment: Edited again based on your last fiddle @Max.

Comment: I do appreciate your effort Sydeen! It's true that forcing the entire column to the right of the viewport technically keeps fixed div within the relative parent. However I wouldn't say this is ideal though since it forces the sidebar to be on the right of the viewport, creating an awkward an variable gap between the main column and the sidebar column.

Comment: That being said I don't see any other answers. Will mark yours as correct if no one else chimes in

Comment: @Max, tweaked it a bit, sidebar is on left now as required and I also removed the margin between sidebar and main content, aligned main content to the top as well, it should all be even and aligned when resizing.

Answer (score 0):

if you intent to center align, you can use `left: 50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);` to both `.column` and `.sticky`

http://jsfiddle.net/vgc1ekbg/5/

Comment: Thanks! However I am not trying to center the sidebar. Part of the challenge here is that, in a two column layout, the distance from either the left or right end of the viewport can very. I've added another fiddle illustrating the issue within the context of a two-column layout